# JQuery UI Sortable putting blank positions in only Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I've got a meeting minutes/actions application that is having a few problems with Jquery UI sortable.

I've uploaded a screencast of my problem:
http://screencast.com/t/YCiuJ3YS

This only happens in Chrome, firefox4 and IE8 are fine. Any other browser is irrelevant.

Basically my task page loads like this:
[image: page as its loaded]

Then the user can collapse an action group

[image: minimize a heading]

they can also drag and drop tasks in between groups. The picture below shows me using the Jquery UI sortable and I'm dragging it over the top of

[image: drag the task over the minimized area]

after doing this, for some reason it leaves the blank space there that it created for the placeholder. If I drag multiple times, this will just add more and more space.

[image: blank space remains]

I had a look in the DOM using the inspector to the left and I can't see any changes there that weren't reversed when I finished dragging. I'm using the latest Jquery UI, Jquery and Chrome.

ANyone got any ideas of where i cna look?

Comment: You probably already know this, but the only think that seems logical to me is that it's related to the fact that not all the children of the `tbody` are sortable. I would look more into what's chrome doing when jQueryUI creates the placeholder with `visibility:none` when you hover over the `tr.groupHeader`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion of what might be the same problem:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-problem-on-chrome-browser

The solution discussed is to add this to the table style:

```
border-spacing: 0;
```

Apparently Webkit calculates the height of `tr` elements incorrectly otherwise.